# Use Excel VBA to insert table data into a list box

Tags: excel, vba

Update: Did some research and have the code below now

I've been helped quite a bit by you code gods today, so here's another question about something I've never done in Excel VBA before:

I've got some code that selects values from a master table, creates a smaller temporary table, then sorts the table. That's simple enough, but what I'd really like to do is add these values to a form control List Box. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim dateSel As Variant
    Dim sevLev, i, rw As Integer
    Dim dRange, keyRange, listRange As Range
    Dim listArray() As String

    sevLev = 1
    dateSel = "12/4/2019"

    With Sheets("All_Risk_Report")
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter _
            field:=2, _
            Criteria1:=dateSel
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter _
            field:=13, _
            Criteria1:=sevLev
    End With

    Sheets("All_Risk_Report").Range("A1:AZ50000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TempTable2"

    Sheets("All_Risk_Report").Range("F:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("TempTable2").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

    Sheets("All_Risk_Report").Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("TempTable2").Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial

    Sheets("All_Risk_Report").Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("TempTable2").Cells(1, 3).PasteSpecial

    Sheets("All_Risk_Report").Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("TempTable2").Cells(1, 4).PasteSpecial

    Sheets("All_Risk_Report").ShowAllData

    Set dRange = Sheets("TempTable2").Range("A1:D500")
    Set keyRange = Sheets("TempTable2").Range("A1:A500")

    dRange.Sort key1:=keyRange, Header:=xlYes

    Set listRange = Sheets("TempTable2").Range("A1:D500")

    With Sheets("Calendar").Shapes.Range(Array("List Box 1"))
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = listRange.Columns.Count

        ReDim MyArray(listRange.Rows.Count, listRange.Columns.Count)

        rw = 0

        For i = 1 To listRange.Rows.Count
            For j = 0 To listRange.Columns.Count
                MyArray(rw, j) = listRange.Cells(i, j + 1)
            Next
            rw = rw + 1
        Next

        .List = MyArray

        .TopIndex = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm not sure exactly how to go about this. I've got the table already created, but I've not used form controls much.

Effectively, this will be a miniature scroll-able window within the sheet itself containing a small subset of data. Please let me know if that makes sense and if you have any advice/suggestions/tips. Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific problem? Does the code error? Does it not do what you want?

Comment: Currently, the code throws the following error:

Run-Time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property or method.

I've never done this type of interface in Excel before, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: which line generates the error?

Comment: It's the final WITH statement at the end of the code - once it hits the .Clear function, I get the error.

Comment: It's because the `Shape` object does not have a `Clear` method. I suggest assigning the shape to a `ListBox` object variable, then you can work with that as intended.